# Best practice values for Perl split function limit parm

Tags: perl, split, limit

I am parsing a string in a subroutine that specifies a fixed number of parameters and two optional parameters. N.B. I also specify the parameter string being used.

This parameter string is of the form:

```
local_fs_name rem_fs_name timeout diff_limit hi hihi (rem_hi) (rem_hihi)
```

so definitely six parameters with two optional parameters for a max of eight.

Should the upper limit be set to the maximum number of parameters or one more than the maximum, i.e. eight or nine?

Comment: Excellent! No one just coped and pasted the output from perldoc -f split!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only reasons to limit the number of fields `split` returns that I can think of are either for  efficiency purposes (and your subroutine would have to be called a *lot* with *very many* more parameters than required for this to matter) or if you *really* want to keep the separators in the final field.

You shouldn't be using `split` to verify the number of parameters. Fetch *all* of them into an array and then verify the contents of the array. Something like this:

```
my $params = 'local_fs_name rem_fs_name timeout diff_limit hi hihi rem_hi rem_hihi';
my @params = split ' ', $params;

if (@params < 6 or @params > 8) {
  die "Usage: mysub local_fs_name rem_fs_name timeout diff_limit hi hihi [rem_hi [rem_hihi]]\n";
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Borodin, I totally agree about splitting into an array and then checking the number of chunks received! Only trouble is seriously infected with the "but we've always done it that way" mentality. Given the size of the systems and the amount of existing code involved, I can understand to a certain extent their approach.

Comment: It's not an efficiency question. It actually affects the result.

Answer (score 1):

It's not a style (best practice) question.

```
split ' ', $_
```

and

```
split ' ', $_, 6
```

produce different results when 7+ args are provided.

```
>perl -E"say +( split ' ', 'a b c d e f g'    )[5]"
f

>perl -E"say +( split ' ', 'a b c d e f g', 6 )[5]"
f g
```

My best guess is that don't want to limit.

Then there's the question of whether you want to keep trailing fields or not.

```
>perl -E"@a=split(' ', 'a b c d e '    ); say 0+@a;"
5

>perl -E"@a=split(' ', 'a b c d e ', -1); say 0+@a;"
6
```

My best guess is trailing whitespace isn't significant.